# Java Reading in Info from .dat Files

Tags: java, input, filestream, bufferedreader

Its been a few years since I've input `.dat` files into a `Java` program, and now I need to for this project. I remember back then I used the `Scanner` class, but looking through the internet for solutions, it seems like there's a lot of options; things like `BufferedReader` and `FileStream` classes that I've never used before, or at least don't remember using.. Anyway, my question is:

If I'm reading in .dat files of the format:

```
998763264      EGCDGHIJJ

697724736      GDHECHHJG
etc.
```

What `class(es)` would you recommend I implement to handle this input? / Can you give me an example of said class being used to read in a file?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Are your files text files or do they contain binary data? The "dat" file name extension is used generically for "data files" which means that the extension says absolutely nothing about what is stored in the file.

Comment: If you can, try to explain what's the content of this files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your .dat file is a text file which contains patterns you provided, Scanner seems is a good solution for you.

Try this code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.dat"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\w\d]*)\s*");
while (sc.findWithinHorizon(p, 0) != null)
{
  MatchResult m = sc.match();
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest using the FileInputStream and an InputStreamReader.

You can find an usage example in this tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstreamreader.html

In your example, you could use the reader.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) method to specifically read the desired chunks of characters.